# How to hide external AAR files from developer

Tags: android

I am making an SDK that a developer would use by just calling one method from a class, we'll call it `SdkManager`. This class has 2 static methods that the developer can use. So the developer would call something like `SdkManager.startSdk(params..)`. The `startSdk` method basically calls an Activity that contains a bunch of fragments and layouts etc...

The only file and methods I want the user to have access to is the `SdkManager`. But right now when the sdk is imported (via aar) they can see all of the files when they start typing in the name of the file. So for example, if there is a file named `SdkApi` and the developer starts typing `SdkA..` they will see the file.

The good is as far as I can tell they can't enter the file to see the code, but I don't want them to even see all of the files populate their autocomplete.

I tried setting the files to private but then `SdkManager` does not have access to them, and then if I try setting the files to `internal` the `SdkManager` gives me an error:

```
'public' subclass exposes its 'internal' supertype
```

Comment: "if I try setting the files to internal the SdkManager gives me an error" -- AFAIK, that error should only appear for types exposed by `SdkManager`, such as parameters or return types on those two functions. For those, you have no choice but to let the developer have access to them, as otherwise they cannot use your API. You could eliminate those types from that API, restricting yourself to common types like `String` and `Boolean`, if you want. In principle, `internal` should work for everything else.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to hide res files?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources